# Import data into SQLite Android app Database

Tags: java, android, mysql, sqlite, relational-database

When I connect a new Client to a MySql server database i need to synchronize all data ( I mean copy all data from server to Client - SQLite). My first idea is duping data from mysql and import everything into Sqlite but I dont't know how.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Sequel (Ruby ORM) has a command line tool for dealing with databases, you must have ruby installed, then:

```
$ gem install sequel mysql sqlite3 
  $ sequel mysql://user:password@host/database -C sqlite://db.sqlite
```

There are many tools available to do this.

1. **mysql2sqlite**- Shell script that converts a mysqldump file into Sqlite3 compatible SQL file. It uses awk for speed and portability. Runs on Windows with the Cygwin tool for Windows.
2. **DBConvert for SQLite&MySQL, DBSync for SQLite&MySQL** DBConvert for SQLite & MySQL and DBSync for SQLite & MySQL are reliable bi-directional database migration software which allow you to convert and synchronize databases from SQLite to MySQL or from MySQL to SQLite. DBConvert Product Line contains tools for MS SQL Server, MySQL, PostgreSQL, Microsoft Access, Microsoft Excel, FoxPro database conversion and synchronization as well. Welcome to evaluate!

For complete visit https://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=ConverterTools